# node module gitignores its own node_modules directory, breaking Heroku deploy

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm

I'm using the `aws-sdk` module, which has a `.gitignore` file that ignores its own `node_modules` directories, breaking my Heroku deployment.

Is there a proper way to deal with this sort of situation? When I `heroku bash` I see that the dependencies are missing from `aws-sdk` it has no `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Are you checking in `node_modules` as part of your git project?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 always do. my temporary fix is to remove the .gitignore from `aws-sdk` module. Seems strange that such a popular module wouldn't work out of the box on Heroku though...

Comment: Generally speaking, us Nodeists on Heroku don't check in `node_modules` (`npm shrinkwrap` is just as good, and is much smaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, Heroku will run `npm install` for you after each deploy, but *only* if the `node_modules` folder is not already present.

You have two major options:

- Stop checking in `node_modules` and switch to `npm shrinkwrap` to keep exact versions
- Remove `.gitignore` from `aws-sdk` (not recommended, as you're modifying packages)

I suggest the first, as it allows you to keep the functionality checking in `node_modules` gives you, without losing anything or modifying other's packages.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `npm install` as a part of your deployment script should take care of it for you assuming that you are listing `aws-sdk` as a dependency in your `package.json`.

Comment: I'll try this next time I have access. I was under the impression that Heroku atuomatically npm-installs on every deploy?

Comment: Even if it does, it only does it at the root level